# How to open links in a new tab/window using CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Is it possible to style the hyperlink tag in CSS in such a way that when a link is clicked it opens it in a new tab or window? I know the solution in HTML and JavaScript/jQuery, yet is it possible to specify this attribute using a stylesheet? Also note that this question is important because it could possibly save me many keystrokes and code clutter. Thanks for your mind and time. =)

HTML:

```
target="_blank"
```

jQuery/JavaScript:

```
window.open($(this).attr("href"), '_blank', 'modal=yes');
```

Css:

```
.class a {
 ???
}
```

Comment: no thats not possible

Comment: If by "save [you] many keystrokes", you mean that you have a lot of links that you'd have to put `target="_blank"` on, then use code editing tools with find/replace functionality.

Comment: Well, that would clutter my code quiet a bit more than it already is. It's ok if I have to, but it would be best if the HTML code could be minimalist as possible.

Comment: So use `$('a.x').attr('target', '_blank')` for all links with "x" class, or remove ".x" for all links. If you don't want to use jQuery, try `var s = document.getElementsByClassName('x'); for (var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) s[i].setAttribute('target', '_blank');` for pure JS. I'm affraid it can't be done simplier, if only SOME links are to be affected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Seems it's not supported by current browsers, refer to http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_target-new.asp